# Abstract and Interface Method usage in my Class

Tags: java, interface, abstract

I am trying to implement a Java program but before going into that, I am confused with regard to methods being used in an interface or an abstract class.
Can somebody guide me on this and provide the reasons for doing so?
I am new to Java.

Here are the some of the methods.

**Interface class:**

```
public interface SampleInterface 
{
    void AddData();
    void DisplayData(int key,String value);
    void DisplayAllData();
    void DeleteData(int key,String value);
    void UpdateData(int key,String value);
    void IndexSearchdata(int key);
    void SortingObjDesc();
    void SortingObjAsc();
}
```

**abstract Class**:

```
public abstract class SampleAbstract 
{
    abstract void AddData();
    abstract void DisplayData(int key,String value);
    abstract void DisplayAllData();
    abstract void DeleteData(int key,String value);
    abstract void UpdateData(int key,String value);
    abstract void IndexSearchdata(int key);
    abstract void SortingObjDesc();
    abstract void SortingObjAsc();
}
```

Comment: Thank you for providing the code in context of your question. However, please [edit] and clarify because _what you're trying to do_ and are confused about is not entirely clear.

Comment: I'm trying to understand your question a little better. Are you trying to determine what methods can go in an abstract class verses what ones can go in an interface?

Comment: thank for reply those are the set of method i can implement by own so before to use i need to implement  these method in interface or abstract to learn there usage now i created these way but i dono which method i  can used in interface or  in abstract so only i approached here ..kindly provide general idea for those method which class i need to implement

Comment: @augray u r correct .that is what i want...

Comment: here i am not asking about comparsion those are the method i want to implement but dono which method go which class